# In matlab, how can I zoom in on a plot in my script

Tags: matlab, zooming

I'd like to zoom in on a plot using a script.  I'm only interested in horizontally constrained zooming.  So I'd like to do something like

```
p = plot(myData);
z = zoom;
set(z, 'ZoomInToPoints' , [50 100]);
```

or

```
p = plot(myData);
myZoom([50, 100]);
```

So either of these functions would zoom into a plot like when you zoom in with the magnifying glass tool.  I only specify two points because I only want to zoom horizontally.

Note, I've already tried to use xlim for this.  While it works, it doesn't let me use the command `text` on my plots, which I need.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't let me use the command `text`" after using `xlim`? The function `xlim` simply sets the x-axis limits. It shouldn't affect calls to `text`.

Comment: None of the text actually shows up on the plot.  It might still be working but putting the text in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm pretty zoom isn't going to solve your problem. You'll have to edit the text location.

Comment: Well, when I zoom in with the magnifying glass everything works fine.  Is there no way to zoom in by issuing a command in my script?

Comment: This behavior is a little strange. Perhaps you can give us more of your code so we can see if there's something else causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to `text` will fix the text at a specific set of coordinates on the graph. Have you tried updating these after calling xlim?

**EDIT:** You can always adjust the text position:

```
x=1:.1:10;
y=sin(.1*x);
plot(x,y)
text(6,.8,'test') %#Sample figure

F=get(0,'children'); %#Figure handle
A=get(F,'Children'); %#Axes handle
T=findobj(A,'Type','text'); %# Text handle
oldxlim=xlim; %#grab the original x limits before zoom
oldpos=get(T,'Position'); %#get the old text position
set(A,'xlim',[5 15]); %#Adjust axes
newxlim=xlim;
newpos=[(oldpos(1)-oldxlim(1))*(diff(newxlim))...
/(diff(oldxlim))+newxlim(1) oldpos(2:end)]; 
%#interpolate to place the text at the same spot in the axes
set(T,'Position',newpos) %#Finally reset the text position
```

Not pretty, but it should work. If you have more than one annotation per axes or axes per figure, you can always throw the above code in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with `text` and `xlim`? Is this not the type of behavior you want?

```
plot(1:100,randn(100,1))
text(80,1.5,'text')
set(gca,'XLim',[70 100]) % notice that text stays at same point in "data space" but moves in "axis space"
text(80,1,'text2'); % new text appears in axis space as well
```

If I'm misunderstanding and you want text to appear at a specific point in your axis space (not the data space that `text` uses) regardless of how zoomed in you are, you can create another set of axes for your text:

```
inset_h = axes('position',[0.5 0.5 0.2 0.2])
set(inset_h,'Color','none'); axis off
text(0,0,'text')
```