# How can I add a zoomed image of a detail of a curve to a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I have a Matlab plot that displays a curve. I would like to add a zoomed detail of the curve on top of the plot

For example

[image]

Is there a way to obtain this in Matlab? (I expect it to be easy in LaTeX, but I am looking for a way to do it without LaTeX.)

[Remark: I have found this image somewhere but I forgot to include the reference.]

Comment: It is simple. Define new axes, assign same `line` to it and set the `xlim` and `ylim` properties to fit your needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390159/in-matlab-how-can-i-zoom-in-on-a-plot-in-my-script?rq=1 - isn't this somehow a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, it probably is a duplicate.